# How Do I Prevent AddThis From Using Cookies On My Site?

Tags: javascript, cookies, privacy, addthis

I'm using the [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) component on a site to add social-bookmarking functionality. However I don't want their code adding cookies to my visitors.

How can I use the component but prevent it from using cookies?

Comment: Drive-by downvote? I've posted this because AddThis don't make it obvious how to opt-out and it might save someone 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for making AdBlock plus not report ads on my website. We don't have any, but AddThis counts as such even though nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `data_use_cookies` config parameter when setting up the component:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {data_use_cookies_ondomain: !1, data_use_cookies: !1};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-5278666D66d6d6"></script>
```

Comment: I've recently upgraded to version 5.0.5 of the plugin and there's no sign of the word "cookies" in the code, so it may not pay attention to it any more.

Comment: As of April 18, 2016, this code (or similar JavaScript found elsewhere on the web) no longer works. If you the AddThis toolbox to you site, cookies are placed on your site. I've asked a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36684920/preventing-addthis-from-setting-cookies-or-documenting-the-purpose-of-these).