# Preventing AddThis from setting cookies (or documenting the purpose of these)?

Tags: javascript, cookies, addthis

[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) provides a configurable toolbox that allow visitors to share content on your site through social media.

When this toolbox is active on my site, 6 third party cookies and 2 first party cookies is set as shown in the screen-shot below:

[image: Cookies set byAdd this]

I don't subscribe to AddThis analytics.  My *only* use of the toolbox is to make it simple for my users to share my site's content on social media.

There exists recipes like [this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218458/how-do-i-prevent-addthis-from-using-cookies-on-my-site) that tells you that you can embed some JavaScript to set options such as `data_use_cookies` false in `addthis_config`. As far as I am able to tell, these methods for preventing cookies being set by AddThis no longer works.

In order to comply with the [EU cookie directive](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm) I either need to remove these cookies, or to get informed consent from visitors (which means I need to document and inform visitors about their *purpose*).

Hence my questions:

1. I really want to prevent AddThis from using cookies on my site. Is there a way to do this in 2016?
2. If it is no longer possible to prevent AddThis from using cookies (without disabling the AddThis toolbox), is there documentation (by AddThis or others) that explains what the *purpose* of these are?

The only thing I've found so far is the [AddThis privacy policy](http://www.addthis.com/privacy).  This page is not very helpful as it contains misleading statements like this:

> “We don't install any tracking software on your computer.”

Since cookies *are* “tracking software” for all intents and purposes, this statement is obviously false.

As for *purpose*, there is a partial answer at [AddThis support sub-site](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/327365-cookie-audit), but it leaves out `vc` and the two first-party cookies it sets.

*Cookiepedia* explains `__atuvc`, but not [`__atuvs`](https://cookiepedia.co.uk/cookies/__atuvs).

Comment: Why do you think AddThis is providing this free service? Because they are nice people and philanthropists or because they want to sell the tracked user data?

Comment: While I had *hoped* that the function to disable cookies was still there (they *used* to let you do this), there is a fallback question (if the answer to my first question is "no".): *What is the purpose of these cookies?* That is still answerable and will be accepted if given.

Comment: Another implication of these cookies is that they may prevent page from http caching because of their random nature.

Answer (score 1):

AddThis widget uses a global configuration variable called `addthis_config` [here the Doc](https://www.addthis.com/academy/the-addthis_config-variable/).

but there are more configurations than those mentioned!

After calling the widget (be sure to remove the async attribute) put this code

```
var addthis_config = {
   data_use_cookies_ondomain: !1,
   data_use_cookies: !1
}
```

This prevent the creation of *__atuvc* and *__atuvs*.
But there still be another created cookies.

Comment: This suggestion is explicitly mentioned in the question, with "As far as I am able to tell, these methods for preventing cookies being set by AddThis no longer works."